# How to separate a UTF-8 file into separate rows (comma delimited) using python?

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

I am trying to convert a UTF-16 file to a UTF-8 file (as I am using the python csv module which apparently does not handle UTF-16 files). I then want to delimit this UTF-8 file so I can import it into a postgres table using a simple row.strip() method. This python file looks like:

```
with codecs.open(sourcefile, 'rU', 'UTF-16') as infile:
   with open(sourcefile + '.utf8', 'wb') as outfile:
       for line in infile:
           outfile.write(line.encode('utf8'))


with open(sourcefile + '.utf8', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        print row[1]
```

I am unable to separate the rows though as row appears to only have one index in it and printing row[1] gives me in an index range - how do I split this file?

Excel row:

```
15,"1/2 TYPE A","98","MCDS, TX","XA","852","TX","955","148","HAPPY, TX",,"$0.00","0","0.00","$1,504","179","0.00%","100.00%","0"
32,"1/2 TYPE B","98","MCDS, MI","XA","252","MI","72","925","HAPPY, MI",,"$0.00","0","0.00","$2,504","225","0.00%","100.00%","0"
```

My apologies for not being very descriptive. Basically the input file is a UTF-16 file. I used to open the file with excel, separate the one column into many columns with delimiter ',' and save it as a csv file. I then ran that manipulated csv file through a python script that was able to read a csv file and strip the rows and import the data into a postgres database.

The original import part of the python script (when I separate by delimiter ',') looks like this (simplified version):

```
 for row in reader:
    arg = {
            'item_number': row[0].strip(),
            'item_size': row[1].strip(),
            'description': row[2].strip(),
            #etc...
        }
        cur.execute(
            """INSERT INTO 
            "Sales"("ITEM_NUMBER","ITEM_SIZE","DESCRIPTION"")
             select
                %(item_number)s, 
                %(item_size)s )
                %(description);""", arg)
```

However, I now want to be able to simply run the UTF-16 file with my python script to import the data into postgres so I do not have to open the file at all in excel. I would like to do this by transforming the file into a UTF-8 file then somehow stripping each row and importing it into my database.

I have been able to successfully transform the file into UTF-8 but now I have the issue where the UTF-8 file is essentially a bunch of lines that are seen as "one column". How would I go about stripping each row? I can not do a simple row[0].strip() as there are some commas in the files that belong to descriptions.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, but… if you saw the Note at the top of the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) docs that tells you that 2.x `csv` doesn't support Unicode, did you not see the link to [examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv-examples) below that show how you can process Unicode CSV files with a simple wrapper?

Comment: What do you see in your `.utf8` version if you check it manually? Also, can you clarify the desired output and what you're seeing instead?

Comment: Even better, can you upload a sample UTF16 file that we can test this against?

Comment: When I take exactly those two lines, save them to a UTF-16 text file, and run your code exactly as posted here, I get two 19-column rows, so your code prints out `1/2 TYPE A` then `1/2 TYPE B`. So, clearly that isn't your input. The problem you need to solve is that your input doesn't look like you think it does, and without seeing your actual input, nobody can help you solve that.

Comment: @abarnert: Isn't that note self-contradictory, as it goes on: "Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe"

Comment: @Deduplicator: No. It can handle UTF-8 by not decoding it and pretending it's ASCII. The only characters it cares about are your delimiter (default `','`), your quote character (default `"`), newlines, and (because of a bug) NULs. Since all of those are the same in UTF-8 and ASCII, it gets away with UTF-8 just fine. The same is true for many other encodings—but not for, e.g., UTF-16.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Also, I think what it's trying to get across is that you shouldn't give it Unicode as in "decoded to `unicode` instead of `str`" input. (This is in contrast to the 3.x version, which wants decoded text—and the third-party module that the stdlib module is based on, which, IIRC, claimed to support `unicode` but didn't do it very well.)

Comment: *Aside*: your code is subject to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating an intermediate file, just use the transform described [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples) (search for `unicode_csv_reader`). For convenience, I have converted the generators to generator expressions:

```
import codecs
import csv

sourcefile = 'csv16.csv'
with codecs.open(sourcefile, 'rU', 'UTF-16') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader((line.encode('utf-8')
                         for line in infile),
                        delimiter=',')
    for row in ([item.decode('utf-8')
                 for item in row]
                for row in reader):
        print u'/'.join(row)
```

I have tested the code above against the following file, saved as Big-endian UTF-16:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
"98°","①", "®©§™"
```

Output:

```
1/2/3/4
5/6/7/8
98°/①/ "®©§™"
```